# Getting an EOFError when getting large files with Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I'm trying to write a quick python script to grab some logs with sftp. My first inclination was to use Pysftp, since it seemed like it made it very simple. It worked great, until it got to a larger file. I got an error while getting any file over about 13 MB. I then decided to try writing what I needed directly in Paramiko, rather than relying on the extra layer of Pysftp. After figuring out how to do that, I ended up getting the exact same error. Here's the Paramiko code, as well as the trace from the error I get. Does anyone have any idea why this would have an issue pulling any largish files? Thanks.

```
# Create tranport and connect
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, 22))
transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

# List of the log files in c:
files = sftp.listdir('c:/logs')
# Now pull them, logging as you go
for f in files:
    if f[0].lower() == 't' or f[:3].lower() == 'std':
      logger.info('Pulling {0}'.format(f))
      sftp.get('c:/logs/{0}'.format(f), output_dir +'/{0}'.format(f))

# Close the connection
sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

And here's the error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pull_logs.py", line 420, in <module> main()
  File "pull_logs.py", line 410, in main
    pull_logs(username, host, password, location)
  File "pull_logs.py", line 142, in pull_logs
    sftp.get('c:/logs/{0}'.format(f), output_dir +'/{0}'.format(f))
  File "/Users/me/my_site/site_packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 676, in get
    size = self.getfo(remotepath, fl, callback)
  File "/Users/me/my_site/site_packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 645, in getfo
    data = fr.read(32768)
  File "/Users/me/my_site/site_packages/paramiko/file.py", line 153, in read
    new_data = self._read(read_size)
  File "/Users/me/my_site/site_packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 152, in _read
    data = self._read_prefetch(size)
  File "/Users/me/my_site/site_packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 132, in _read_prefetch
    self.sftp._read_response()
  File "/Users/me/my_site/site_packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 721, in _read_response
    raise SSHException('Server connection dropped: %s' % (str(e),))
paramiko.SSHException: Server connection dropped:
```

Comment: 1) Check if you are able to download large files using any (GUI) SFTP client at all. 2) Check server-side log for details on the disconnect. Edit your question to include your findings.

Comment: See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170689/501765), that may help in such a case too