# Paramiko "OSError: Failure" when trying to put large file to SFTP server

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

My task is to perform some action on data queried from a database and then store the output on an SFTP server.
The script performing all of this is executed on a VM running Windows Server 2016 Standard through task scheduler.

There are a total of 4 files which I should copy at the end of the script from some location on a shared drive (accessible from the VM that's running the script) to the SFTP server. These files have size:

1. ~25 MB
2. ~55 MB
3. ~900 MB
4. ~2 GB

Here's the final part of the script, where the copying process takes place:

```
hostname = 'ftp_server_name'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
keypath = 'Sftp_Key'
known_hosts = 'known_hosts.txt'

import paramiko

mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(keypath, password)

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.load_host_keys(known_hosts)
ssh_client.connect(
    hostname=hostname,
    username=username,
    allow_agent=True,
    pkey=mykey,
    disabled_algorithms={'pubkeys': ['rsa-sha2-256', 'rsa-sha2-512']}
)

tr = ssh_client.get_transport()
tr.default_max_packet_size = 10000000000
tr.default_window_size = 10000000000

sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()

sftp_client.put(
    r'\\path\to\origin\on\shared\drive\file_1.csv',
    '/root/folder/path/to/destination/file_1.csv'
)

sftp_client.put(
    r'\\path\to\origin\on\shared\drive\file_2.csv',
    '/root/folder/path/to/destination/file_2.csv'
)

sftp_client.put(
    r'\\path\to\origin\on\shared\drive\file_3.csv',
    '/root/folder/path/to/destination/file_3.csv'
)

sftp_client.put(
    r'\\path\to\origin\on\shared\drive\file_4.csv',
    '/root/folder/path/to/destination/file_4.csv'
)
print(sftp_client.listdir())

sftp_client.close()
ssh_client.close()
```

As you can see, I am

- spelling out entirely the destination file name (as indicated in the documentation and as suggested everywhere on SO)
- getting the transport and increasing the sizes (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170689/4349869))

It all goes well until the final one (`file_4`), at which I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "H:\folder\scripts\test_sftp_copy.py", line 45, in <module>
    ftp_client.put(

  File "C:\Users\MeUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 759, in put
    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)

  File "C:\Users\MeUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 716, in putfo
    size = self._transfer_with_callback(

  File "C:\Users\MeUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 679, in _transfer_with_callback
    writer.write(data)

  File "C:\Users\MeUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\file.py", line 405, in write
    self._write_all(data)

  File "C:\Users\MeUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\file.py", line 522, in _write_all
    count = self._write(data)

  File "C:\Users\MeUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_file.py", line 208, in _write
    t, msg = self.sftp._read_response(req)

  File "C:\Users\A-AChiap\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 874, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)

  File "C:\Users\A-AChiap\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 907, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(text)

OSError: Failure.
```

The weird thing is that, once the code breaks after attempting to `put` the fourth file (raising the `OSError: failure`), I cannot put any other file in the server any more.

So, for instance, if I try copying again `file_1.csv`, I would get the `OSError: failure` error right away.
In this case, I need to wait several hours or try again the next day.
This feels like an issue on the SFTP side.

Can anybody with more experience or knowledge of the matter comment? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *"Failure"* is an error message for SFTP error code 4, returned by the OpenSSH SFTP server for various problems, for which there's no more specific code in the SFTP protocol version 3. While the server should at least return a specific plain-text error message, it fails to do so.

Common reasons you may get the generic *"Failure"* error message, while uploading are:

- Uploading a file to a full filesystem (HDD).
- Exceeding a user disk quota.

That even matches the other symptoms you have: The problem happens with the largest file. And you cannot upload any file after the failed transfer.

For details, see [SFTP Status/Error Code 4 (Failure)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes#code_4).